# Append element to an array in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, server, for-loop, client

I am trying to write a for loop to append elements dynamically to an array. However, the dimensions of the array change on every loop run, throwing off error.

```js
var arr = 1
for (var i=0;i<4;++i){
  var newval = somefunction()
  arr = ee.Array.cat([newvar,arr],0)
}
print(arr)
```

Error:
`Array.cat: Arrays must have same dimensionality. Expected 0, found 1 for array 1.`

EDIT:  The new value to be appended is coming out of a `for` loop, so I can't use a list.map or iterate function

Answer (score 7):

Your code is returning "unexpected" results because you are mixing client-side Javascript control structures with server-side Earth Engine methods. In general, you should avoid doing this. Review the Earth Engine [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) docs page for a complete discussion.

For your simple example, you can use an [ee.List()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eelist) object to accumulate values, and later convert it to an [ee.Array()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eearray):

```js
var first = ee.List([1]);

var list = ee.List.sequence(0, 4);
var iter_function = function (num, list){
  num = ee.Number(num);
  var new_value = num.multiply(num);
  return ee.List(list).add(new_value);
};

var resulting_list = list.iterate(iter_function, first);
print('resulting_list', resulting_list);

var resulting_array = ee.Array(resulting_list);
print('resulting_array', resulting_array);
```

However, if your actual use case is too complex for ee.List() objects, you can iterate using ee.Array() objects:

```js
var first = ee.Array([1]);

var list = ee.List.sequence(0, 4);
var iter_function = function (num, list){
  num = ee.Number(num);
  var new_value = ee.Array([num.multiply(num)]);
  return ee.Array.cat([list, new_value]);
};

var resulting_array = list.iterate(iter_function, first);
print('resulting_array', resulting_array);
```

If processing each element in your list is independent of the others, you can *map* your function across this list using [ee.List.map()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eelistmap) instead:

```js
var list = ee.List.sequence(0, 4);
var map_function = function (num){
  num = ee.Number(num);
  var new_value = num.multiply(num);
  return new_value;
};

var resulting_list = list.map(map_function);
print('resulting_list', resulting_list);

var resulting_array = ee.Array(resulting_list);
print('resulting_array', resulting_array);
```

The moral of this story is: "*Friends don't let friends use loops with big data.*"

Comment: Thanks for explaining it well. But my case really needs to use a for loop, as the `num` variable is coming from a for loop. Is it possible somehow? I have made edits in the question to show this.